# Is HttpWebRequest.Timeout a SendTimeout or a ReceiveTimeout?

Tags: .net, sockets, httpwebrequest

I'm guessing that internally **HttpWebRequest** class is implemented using a `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` class.

If yes, then what would be the equivalent of setting its `Timeout` property? Setting its [*socket.SendTimeout*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendtimeout.aspx) property, or rather [*socket.ReceiveTimeout*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout.aspx) property?

PS: Please don't answer this question by decompiling the code!

Answer (score 0):

With WCF requests, you set the Send or ReceiveTimout when you configure your request binding.

There are a bunch of different binding types depending on what you're doing (TCP, HTTP/s, pipes, etc.), but generally setting the timeouts looks like this:

```
Dim xbinding As System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding = _
          New System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding    

With xbinding
   .SendTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
   .ReceiveTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0) ' ten minutes
   ' you can also set your message limits and such in here. 
End With
```

Obviously, you've go the same thing on the host side.

Comment: Sorry, I'm hip deep in wcf development and HTTPWebRequests are how I've set up the client side of things. Hopefully, the bit about timeouts is of some use.

Answer (score 0):

The Remarks section in the [WebRequest.Timeout property documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx) says:

> The Timeout property affects only synchronous requests made with the GetResponse method.

That would indicate that you're receiving data, meaning that setting it is analogous to setting a socket's `ReceiveTimeout` property.

That said, a later remark states:

> The WebRequest class is an abstract class. The actual behavior of WebRequest instances at run time is determined by the descendant class returned by the WebRequest.Create method. For more information about default values and exceptions, see the documentation for the descendant classes, such as HttpWebRequest and FileWebRequest.

So it really depends on the concrete class. [HttpWebRequest.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx), for example, has somewhat different behavior.

In the case of `HttpWebRequest`, the `Timeout` is essentially a socket receive buffer timeout when you call `GetResponse`. But the `Timeout` also applies to `GetRequestStream`, which has no real Socket analogue. Note again that this applies only to *synchronous* requests.

Comment: sorry I meant HttpWebRequest.TimeOut, I'll change my question, ok?